# Non-clustered ActorSystem

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I have a question that I find very confusing in documentation on `Akka Streams` and `Akka Actors` in general.

Because docs said that Akka Streams cannot be clustered , and they run on ActorSystem and Materializer. So...

Is `ActorSystem("some-actor-system")` implementation clustered or not ?

I saw some clustered implementation of ActorSystem , but how do you , or do you implement non-clustered ActorSystem ?

Comment: How do you define the properties "clustered" and "non-clustered" for an actor system? Is any akka `ActorSystem` which is not used by akka `Cluster` "non-clustered"?

Comment: Yes exactly , thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration determines whether the actor system will try to connect to seed-nodes (a.k.a. "creating a cluster") or not. More details can be found in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/java/cluster-usage.html).

Comment: Sorry, here is the [scala documentation page](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/cluster-usage.html)